# What do Jehovah's Witnesses believe about the nature of God?

Tags: trinity, jehovahs-witnesses, christology

What do Jehovah's Witnesses believe about the nature of God and, specifically, Jesus?

A common Christian belief is that God is One in Three co-equal, co-eternal Persons--the Father, the Son, and the Spirit.

Do the Jehovah's Witnesses acknowledge this?  If not, what specifically do they believe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Only Jehovah is God; Jesus Christ is Michael the
   archangel. He is different from the other angels in that he was the
   first one created. They quote the following verse to prove that he
   is Michael:

   > 1 Thessalonians 4:14 For the Lord himself will come down from heaven, with a loud command,
   >   with the **voice of the archangel** and with the trumpet call of God, and
   >   the dead in Christ will rise first.
2. Only Jehovah is the true creator. Jehovah created Jesus and then used him to create everything else. So Jesus
   is the creator of everything except that he himself was created by
   God.

   > John 1:3 **Through him** all things were made; without him nothing was
   >   made that has been made.
3. Only Jehovah is omniscient. Jesus does not know
   everything.

   > Matthew 24:36 No one knows about that day or hour, not even the angels
   >   in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father.
4. Only Jehovah is completely holy, not Jesus.

   > Mark 10:18 "Why do you call me good?" Jesus answered. "No one is good
   >   except God alone.

   Jesus, being an angel, cannot be completely holy.

   > Job 4:18 Even in his servants he puts no trust, and his angels he charges with error.
5. Only Jehovah is the eternal King and true Judge. He has submitted
   the judgement of this world to Jesus for the time being but
   ultimately all authority will return to him.

   > 1 Corinthians 15:28 When he has done this, then **the Son himself will
   >   be made subject to him who put everything under him**, so that God may
   >   be all in all.
6. The Holy spirit is Jehovah's active power. It is an impersonal force just
   like wind or fire and does not have a mind or will. This is from
   the July 2006 issue of *Awake!* magazine, published by The Watchtower Bible & Tract Society:

   > When Mary, the mother of Jesus, visited her cousin Elizabeth, the
   >   Bible says that the unborn child in Elizabeth’s womb leaped, “and
   >   Elizabeth was filled with holy spirit.” (Luke 1:41) **Is it reasonable
   >   that a person would be “filled” with another person?**
   >
   > John could hardly have been referring to the holy spirit as a person
   >   when he spoke of baptizing people with it.
   >
   > It is not unusual for God’s Word to personify things that are not a
   >   person. These include wisdom, discernment, sin, death, and undeserved
   >   kindness.
   >
   > **The holy spirit is not a person simply because in some instances it is
   >   personified.**

Comment: Job 4:18 was definitely used out of context - a quote from a man used as a satanic pawn to discourage Job. Have JWs ever used this scripture in this way?

Comment: @user9485 You are correct. Whether or not a JW used that scripture in that way, it does not represent our official beliefs about that scripture for the reason you mentioned. I edited it out of the answer, and made some rewording to number 4. We don't believe that Jesus is exactly unholy in any way, but Jehovah is holy in a way that goes beyond what Jesus claims about himself.

Answer (score 1):

Jehovah’s Witnesses have produced volumes of information showcasing our beliefs on this subject.

A brochure that condenses our beliefs on the trinity doctrine is available [here](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/library/r1/lp-e/all-publications/brochures-and-booklets/trinity-ti).

The forward reads

> People often say they believe in the Trinity, yet they differ in their understanding of it.
> What, exactly, is the Trinity?
> Does the Bible teach it?
> Is Jesus Christ the Almighty God and part of the Trinity?

Contents

Should You Believe It?

How Is the Trinity Explained?

Is It Clearly a Bible Teaching?

How Did the Trinity Doctrine Develop?

What Does the Bible Say About God and Jesus?

Is God Always Superior to Jesus?

The Holy Spirit—God’s Active Force

What About Trinity “Proof Texts”?

Worship God on His Terms

Under the sub heading “Jesus a Separate Creation” on page 14

> Thus, Jesus had an existence in heaven before coming to the earth. But was it as one of the persons in an almighty, eternal triune Godhead? No, for the Bible plainly states that in his prehuman existence, Jesus was a created spirit being, just as angels were spirit beings created by God. Neither the angels nor Jesus had existed before their creation.

Of course this does not mean that Jesus is just another angel. Instead he is the only being directly created by Jehovah God. Every other created thing was created through him. So he is a unique spirit creation with a rank and preeminence over all creation. Jehovah the one uncreated eternal God is the only one Jesus is subject to.

The subject of the nature of God is answered [here](https://www.jw.org/en/library/magazines/g200810/What-Is-the-Nature-of-God/).