# What is the biblical basis for the belief held by Jehovah's Witnesses that Jehovah and Jesus Christ are separate entities?

Tags: biblical-basis, nature-of-god, christology, jehovahs-witnesses

According to Jehovah's witnesses what evidences are there in the Bible that Jehovah is not Jesus Christ? What passages separate them, or declare them as different?

Comment: Related: [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8584/what-do-jehovahs-witnesses-believe-about-the-nature-of-god) and [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59098/did-jws-believe-in-trinity-and-immortality-of-the-soul-before-they-got-their-own)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the Jehovahs Witnesses make the matter pretty clear on their [website](http://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/).

**TL;DR** - Jehovah used to appear to the ancient prophets as "God Almighty", Jesus Christ never identified as "God Almighty".

---

> ## [Does God Have a Name?](http://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/gods-name/)
>
> ### The Bible’s answer
>
> Humans all have personal names. Wouldn’t it be reasonable for God to
>   have a name? Having and using personal names is a vital part of human
>   friendships. Should it be different when it comes to our friendship
>   with God?
>
> In the Bible, God says: “I am Jehovah. That is my name.” ([Isaiah
>   42:8](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/isaiah/42/#v23042008)) Although he also has many titles, such as “**God Almighty**,”
>   “Sovereign Lord,” and “Creator,” he honors his worshippers by inviting
>   them to address him by his personal name.—[Genesis 17:1;](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/genesis/17/#v1017001) [Acts
>   4:24;](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/acts/4/#v44004024) [1 Peter 4:19](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/1-peter/4/#v60004019).
>
> Many translations of the Bible contain God’s personal name at [Exodus
>   6:3.](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/exodus/6/#v2006003) That passage says: “**I used to appear to Abraham, Isaac and
>   Jacob as *God Almighty***, but as respects my name Jehovah I did not
>   make myself known to them.”
>
> Jehovah is a rendering of God’s name in English that has been used for
>   centuries. While many scholars prefer the spelling “Yahweh,” Jehovah
>   is the form of the name that is most widely recognized. The first part
>   of the Bible was written not in English but in Hebrew, a language that
>   is read from right to left. In that language, the divine name appears
>   as four consonants, יהוה. Those four Hebrew characters—transliterated
>   YHWH—are known as the Tetragrammaton.
>
> ---
>
> ## [Is God’s Name Jesus?](http://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/is-gods-name-jesus/)
>
> ### The Bible’s answer
>
> Jesus referred to himself as “God’s Son” or “the Son of God.” ([John
>   10:36;](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/john/10/#v43010036) [11:4](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/john/11/#v43011004)) **Jesus never identified himself as *Almighty
>   God***.
>
> Moreover, Jesus prayed to God. ([Matthew 26:39](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/26/#v40026039)) And while teaching
>   his followers how to pray, Jesus said: “Our Father in the heavens, let
>   your name be sanctified.”—[Matthew 6:9](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/6/#v40006009).
>
> Jesus revealed God’s name when he quoted an ancient passage of
>   Scripture and said: “Hear, O Israel, Jehovah our God is one
>   Jehovah.”—[Mark 12:29](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/mark/12/#v41012029); [Deuteronomy 6:4](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/deuteronomy/6/#v5006004).
>
> ---
>
> ## [Is Jesus Almighty God?](http://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/is-jesus-almighty/)
>
> ### The Bible’s answer
>
> Jesus’ opposers accused him of making himself equal to God. ([John
>   5:18;](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/john/5/#v43005018) [10:30-33](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/john/10/#v43010030-v43010033)) However, Jesus never claimed to be on the
>   same level as Almighty God. He said: “The Father is greater than I
>   am.”—[John 14:28](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/john/14/#v43014028).
>
> Jesus’ early followers did not view him as being equal to Almighty
>   God. For example, the apostle Paul wrote that after Jesus was
>   resurrected, God “exalted him [Jesus] to a superior position.”
>   Obviously, Paul did not believe that Jesus was Almighty God.
>   Otherwise, how could God exalt Jesus to a superior position?
>   —[Philippians 2:9](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/philippians/2/#v50002009).

---

<sup>www.JW.org, Jehovah's Witnesses [Bible Questions Answered](http://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/) - God, Jesus.</sup>

Comment: I'm surprised they don't include that an argument to that effect can be made based on the constant New Testament refrain of "God the Father and our Lord Jesus Christ" (particularly in the Pauline epistles) if you reject the rather contrived Sharpe's rule.

Comment: How does John 10:30 fit in with all of this?

Comment: @Zenon - Because it adds context to *why* the Jews are ready to stone him, which is because they think he's making himself equal to God by saying, " I and the Father are one."

Comment: @ShemSeger I don't understand Phil 2:9 as an argument considering what follows in 2:11.

Comment: @JontheArchitect I can only guess as to what you didn't understand, but 2:11 says that glory should go to God because God was the one who did the exalting. Jesus has such a high position due to the magnitude of God's glory.

Answer (score -2):

As an ex-JW:

- I do not recall a single lecture of the form "Today, we're going to prove that Jesus != God"

Instead, it was things like:

- Jesus = Michael the ArchAngel ( http://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/bible-teach/who-is-michael-the-archangel/ )  [ Mainstream Christianity views this as heretical, since mainstream Christianity views Jesus as God. ]
- Angels are below God
- Therefore, Jesus != God  [ Thus, a heretical conclusion ]

========================

As an aside, this creates all sorts of problems:

- Satan was initially thrown down for wanting to be above God.
- If Jesus = Arch Angel
- If JW believers are to be above Angels (in particular, to judge Angels)
- Then, JW believers have the authority to judge Jesus / be above Jesus -- which is heretical from a mainstream Christianity view.
- This is basically similar to Satan's original sin -- to be above God.

Comment: Although I think most people on this site are also programmers I don't think everyone is going to get the != convention.

Comment: Less of your opinion (which wasn't asked for) and more of theirs (which was) would make this a more focussed answer to the question.

Comment: I upvoted because in my experience as well the logic that C.T. Russell gave was just about that. Jesus is Michael the Archangel. Angels are below God. Jesus is not God. The SDA are similar to JW's in this respect, but they are still Trinitarian. See: [What are the main differences between 7th Day Adventists and Catholic/Protestant churches?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16250) and [What is the origin of the idea that Michael is Jesus?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/18614)

Comment: "This is the step which I view as heretical" - nobody cares what you think.  Sorry if that sounds harsh, but in this SE we stick to verifiable facts, not personal opinions.

Comment: JWs don't believe they're above Jesus. The 144,000 are to be kings and priests over God's Kingdom, ruling alongside Jesus. Humans cannot choose to be members of the 144,000. They are chosen by Christ.