# Differences between paranormal entities like banshees, poltergeists, demons, ghosts, etc..?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

Human history is full of various paranormal entities such as:

- Ghosts
- Demons
- Spirits
- Poltergeists
- Banshees
- Disembodied voices
- Orbs

Some books I have seen even equated extraterrestrial aliens or UFOs with the paranormal entities.

I have previously heard (or read somewhere, I cannot remember which one) that some of these may be souls trapped between heaven and hell, or souls of people who were killed and are looking for justice.

From what I understand though, Jehovah's Witnesses do not believe in the immortality of the soul (as per [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59098/did-jws-believe-in-trinity-and-immortality-of-the-soul-before-they-got-their-own), or the selected answer to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/48322/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-belief-that-people-do-not-go-to-heaven-or-hel)).

With that in mind, do Jehovah's Witnesses have any kind of spirit creature taxonomy for explaining the different kinds of paranormal entities?

Or do you view these as mainly the product of human imagination?

**Update:**
I had assumed that the different paranormal entities have their own separate backstory so to speak. This seems to be to the assumption from sites found through queries such as [this one](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=types%20of%20paranormal%20entities&t=hf&ia=web). For that reason I thought the other question only dealt with "ghosts", but the comment by @4castle does clarify this in my mind (i.e. that all of these phenomena are caused by demons) although now I need to find what the "demons" backstory is according to JWs. That would be a different question however; this one can considered a duplicate.

Comment: There are some cases where a supernatural occurrence is actually a natural one (like [Ball Lightning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning)), but otherwise JWs attribute all of those supernatural things to demons.

Comment: I have read that that UFO stuff is often a religious experience to some people. And it just dawned on me that paranormal entities and aliens are both often described as telepathic. So maybe it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you @4castle, I had assumed that the different paranormal entities have their own separate backstory so to speak. Your comment does clarify this sufficiently and we can keep this as duplicate.

Comment: For the backstory on demons, you can read [this article](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/bible-study/angels-in-the-bible/) starting in paragraph 7.